# Uncaught TypeError: cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a HTML music production program. I am currently working on the note system for when you click on a note, it switches color to black. But, when I use my Javascript function, it shows the error `Uncaught TypeError: cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined`

---

Here is my Javascript. it is incomplete, but if anyone can help, that would be great.

```js
var pattern = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
function switchNote(num, note) {
 var trId = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[note + 8].id;
 pattern[num] = note;
 document.getElementById(trId).lastChild.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
 return "switched";
}
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML? If `lastChild` is not an HTML element, then `.style` will be undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var pattern = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
function switchNote(num, note) {
 var trId = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[note + 8].id;
 pattern[num] = note;
 document.getElementById(trId).children[document.getElementById(trId).children.length].style.backgroundColor = "#000";
 return "switched";
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Can you mark this as the answer then?

Answer (score 1):

It indicates that the `.lastChild` is not a DOM *element* (a node with `.nodeType` of `1`). The `lastChild` is either a textNode or a commentNode and it doesn't have `style` property.

You can use the `lastElementChild` property for getting the last element child.

Another option is using the `.children` property:

```
var children = [].slice.call(element.children);
var last = children[children.length - 1];
// for getting the last 2 children of the element:
// var last2 = children.slice(-2);
```

Note that if the `document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[note + 8]` returns the target element, then there is no need to re-query DOM by using `document.getElementById` method. IDs must be unique and reading the `.id`   property of an element for getting it again by `.getElementById` doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Yes, but how can I access any certain number of a child?